# Numpy index columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 2d matrix `D`

```
array([[1, 1, 8, 8],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [8, 8, 1, 1]])
```

I would like to find each column's lowest value by indexing it with the `amin` array:

```py
amin = D.argmin(0)
amin
```

```
array([0, 0, 2, 2])
```

How do I properly index `D` with `amin` such that the returned array is `array([1, 1, 1, 1])`?

Comment: How do you obtain the vector [1,1,3,1]?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki sorry, the initial question was posed wrong, The vector in question would be `[1, 1, 1, 1]`

Comment: you don't need to do argmin if you want the values. argmin is if you want the indexes. Assuming your array is stored in the variable myArray just do `np.min(myArray, axis=0)`  (where np comes from doing `import numpy as np`)

Comment: This works, but I would like to see the indexing syntax to it using `amin`

Comment: no, its not a school exercise. i find numpy's indexing logic at times very counterintuitive

Comment: `D[amin, np.arange(len(amin))]`, IIUC.

Answer (score 1):

You need a combination of `expand_dims` and `take_along_axis`

```
np.take_along_axis(D, np.expand_dims(amin, 0), 0)
Out[]: array([[1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

This is arguably not the most intuitive formulation, but without going into design philosophy of `numpy`, I can say it's as "pythonic" as possible in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for something more intuitive indeed. I always find myself struggling way too long with such problems. One is wondering why things like `D[:, amin[None,:]]` do not work ...

Answer (score 0):

```
In [99]: D=np.array([[1, 1, 8, 8],
    ...:        [3, 3, 4, 4],
    ...:        [8, 8, 1, 1]])
In [100]: amin = D.argmin(0)
In [101]: amin
Out[101]: array([0, 0, 2, 2])
```

What is `amin`?  It has one value per column, but that value is a row index.  So what you want is:

```
In [102]: D[amin[0], 0]
Out[102]: 1
In [103]: D[amin[2], 2]
Out[103]: 1
```

Or doing all columns at once:

```
In [104]: D[amin, [0,1,2,3]]
Out[104]: array([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Expressions like `D[:, amin]` try to apply `amin` to indexing the columns, not the rows.  And the slice selects all rows at once.  It doesn't pair them up.

May be these versions will make the action clearer:

```
In [105]: D[[0,0,2,2], [0,1,2,3]]
Out[105]: array([1, 1, 1, 1])
In [106]: [D[i,j] for i,j in zip([0,0,2,2],[0,1,2,3])]
Out[106]: [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

`take_along_axis` does the same thing as [104]

```
In [107]: np.take_along_axis(D, amin[None,:],0)
Out[107]: array([[1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

It's a bit cleaner if we tell `argmin` to `keepdims` (a new feature in v 1.22)

```
In [108]: amin = D.argmin(0, keepdims=True)
In [109]: amin
Out[109]: array([[0, 0, 2, 2]])
In [110]: np.take_along_axis(D, amin,0)
Out[110]: array([[1, 1, 1, 1]])
```